# how to convert a read only hibernate session to write during a transaction (Master/Slave DB)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, database-replication

Working with MySql replication with spring+hibernate, I have a quick question;

The transactions that are opened are in read-only mode i.e pointing to slave DB.
What is the best way to convert it to write mode if I want to save/update/delete any thing during that transaction?

I do not want to open a write mode transaction as most of the time I want read stuff.

Do I need to overide the replication Driver/Hibernate template for this thing?

Comment: If a transaction must write, it must not be opened in read-only mode. That's as simple as that. Hibernate will only write what needs to be written, and a read-only transaction is not much faster than a read-write one. Don't try to optimize prematurely.

Comment: In few transaction they are not must write i.e writing is optional based on few conditions or reading.

Comment: Did you find solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We open transactions in read only mode and then convert it to write mode as read only connections will not be an issue as it is with salve DB.

We override the **HibernateTemplate** class and create methods to make session in write mode

```
 public final void writeEnabled(){
    getSession().doWork(jdbcWorkWriteEnabled);
}

public final void writeDisabled(boolean flush){
    if(flush)
        flush();
    getSession().doWork(jdbcWorkWriteDisabled);
}

public static final void writeEnabled(Session session){
    session.doWork(jdbcWorkWriteEnabled);
}

public static final void writeDisabled(boolean flush,Session session){
    if(flush)
        session.flush();
    session.doWork(jdbcWorkWriteDisabled);
}

final static Work jdbcWorkWriteEnabled = new Work(){
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.setReadOnly(false);
    }
};

final static Work jdbcWorkWriteDisabled = new Work(){
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.setReadOnly(true);
    }
};
```

In application logic before write we check 
Connection is in write mode then simply write.
else if connection is readonly then first make it in write mode, do write operation and again make it  back to readonly