# TransactionManager read-only=true does not work with mysql ReplicationDriver

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

We are using com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver to connect Master/Slave. We configure the transactionManager as follow.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txHbAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

I set the read-only parameter to true but it doesn't set `java.sql.Connection.setReadonly()` method to true. All the read queries are still come to master server.

There is an open issue for similar problem [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8303) . Is there anyone having a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have a similar issue... It seems to be refusing the writes on my read-only methods, but it doesn't throw an exception, instead the test case silently passes.  It certainly seems like something is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to write aspect around `@Transactional` annotation, get current running session and then invoke `doWork(Work work)` → and set `connection.setReadOnly` if `@transaction` has readonly attribute set. I have not tried this solution, but I think it should work.

Youu can also refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694254/how-to-convert-a-read-only-hibernate-session-to-write-during-a-transaction-mast).